# How to perform a Bulk Insert in Sybase SQL

Tags: database-performance, bulkinsert, sap-ase, sqlperformance

I need to insert a Big amount of data(Some Millions) and I need to perform it Quickly.
I read about Bulk insert via ODBC on .NET and JAVA But I need to perform it directly on the Database.

I also read about Batch Insert but What I have tried have not seemed to work
[Batch Insert](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00641.1570100/doc/html/jpl1354138857639.html),  [Example](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00641.1570100/doc/html/jpl1347383957878.html)

I'm executing a INSERT SELECT but it's taking something like 0,360s per row, this is very slow and I need to perform some improvements here.

I would really appreciate some guidance here with examples and documentation if possible.

DATABASE: SYBASE ASE 15.7

Comment: you'll need to start with tracking down where the time is being spent ... updating indexes? checking RI constraints? trigger processing? blocking? excessive disk IO times (eg, reading source data from disk, writing log/data pages to disk)?

Comment: Hi Markp, I have improved a lot,after the index work in this morning, last record was 15k updates and 15k inserts in 8 minutes, but still I don't know if this is fast enough, I'll Track Time also. It's great help pointing all that stuff to check, what do you man with blocking?

Comment: Yes I'm writting log to disk! O though that would be a bad practice to not log this activity

Comment: it's not a question of not writing the log to disk, it's a question of how long are the writes (log to disk) taking (ie, do you have slow disks?); as for blocking ... intermittent blocking of your process (by other processes) would show up as 'slowness' during your inserts

Comment: Thanks Markp, can you help me with some documentation on how to performe those analysis. I'm kinda new to developing large sets of data

Comment: found this one: https://www.sqlskills.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/sql-server-performance-tuning-using-wait-statistics-whitepaper.pdf I'll keep searching. thanks!

Comment: I'm doing 19k updates in 3minutes, it's better but not good yet.

Comment: the insert is 16k in 3 seconds, way better. just with index work

Comment: @markp your commend on IO was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on some of the comments ...

- blocking, slow disk IO, and any other 'wait' events (ie, anything other than actual insert/update activity) can be ascertained from the `master..monProcessWaits` table (`where SPID = spid_of_your_insert_update_process`) [see the P&T manual for Monitoring Tables (aka MDA tables)]
- `master..monProcessObject` and `master..monProcessStatement` will show logical/physical IOs for **currently** running queries [again, see P&T manual for MDA tables]
- `master..monSysStatement` will show logical/physical IOs for **recently** completed queries [again, see P&T manual for MDA tables]
- for `UPDATE` statements you'll want to take a look at the query plan to see if you're suffering from a poor join order; also of key importance ... `direct` (fast/good) updates vs `deferred` (slow/bad) updates; `deferred` updates can occur for many reasons ... some fixable, some not ... updating indexed columns, poor join order, updates that cause page splits and/or row forwardings
- RI (PK/FK) constraints can be viewed with `sp_helpconstraint table_name`; query plans will also show the under-the-covers joins required when performing RI (PK/FK) validations during inserts/updates/deletes
- triggers are a bit harder to locate (an official `sp_helptrigger` doesn't show up until ASE 16); check the `sysobjects.[ins|upd|del]trig where name = your_table` - these represent the object id(s) of any insert/update/delete triggers on the table; also check `sysobjects` records where `type = 'TR' and deltrig = object_id(your_table)` - provides support for additional insert/update/delete triggers (don't recall at moment if this is just ASE 16+)
- if triggers are being fired, need to review the associated query plans to make sure the `inserted` and `deleted` tables (if referenced) are driving any queries where these pseudo tables are joined with permanent tables

There are likely some areas I'm forgetting (off the top of my head) ... key take away is that there could be many reasons for 'slow' DML statements.

---

One (relatively) quick way to find out if RI (PK/FK) constraints or triggers are at play ...

```
set showplan on
go
insert/update/delete statements
go
```

Then review the resulting query plan(s); if you see references to any tables other than the ones explicitly listed in the insert/update/delete statements then you're likely dealing with RI constraints and/or triggers.

Comment: Hi markp, Thanks a lot for introducing me such great concepts to look at and explain. this thread have generated an unprecedented quest from my side and now I'm much more familiar with this. My performance have improved a lot and I've dramatically changed my Bulk insert code. Thank you for your Help!

Comment: From what you said, I Just need to Explore more about direct vs deferred Updates

Comment: keep in mind that some deferred updates cannot be eliminated (eg, and UPDATE that updates a column of an index, and UPDATE that updates a variable-length column to a larger value that causes a page split, etc).

Comment: Hi markp! I've been reading that topic in the morning and I'm now familiar with it. Updating index columns will cause index update, and variable-lenght column can cause page split or row forwarding(as you mentioned)! Thanks!!