# How to bulk insert into Sybase database with an auto incremented ID?

Tags: sql, sybase, sybase-ase15

I have a table A which has Id = 0 for some 6k records, another table B in which these IDs are missing. I want to insert these IDs into table B with an auto incremented ID number and update these ID numbers into table A in no particular order. just that there should be no ID = 0 in table A. I'm doing this in Python. is there a faster way of doing this rather than the regular DMLs and for loop which seems to be taking a very long time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exactly which Sybase edition and version are you using?

Comment: @Dai -  I'm using Sybase ASE 16.0

Comment: Use Sybase's `bcp.exe` - and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46443695/how-to-perform-a-bulk-insert-in-sybase-sql

Comment: what do you mean by *`these IDs are missing.`* for table B? they are `0`? they are `NULL`? the table currently has no such column? also, just to be clear ... when you say *`auto incremented ID`* ... you're referring to a column that has the `identity` attribute?

Comment: is the intent: start with an empty table B, the ID column in table B has the `identity` attribute, copy rows from table A to table B so that the new rows in table B end up with system generated ID values, then move these rows back to table A ... in effect updating the ID column in table A with the newly generated `identity` values?

Comment: updating 6K rows should take no more than a second (if that) so not sure how this - *`for loop which seems to be taking a very long time`* - makes sense unless there's something else going on (eg, poorly performing trigger firing on inserts, incorrect/inefficient SQL being used to modify the rows, or perhaps something else ... ?);  it's going to be hard to troubleshoot the performance issue without a lot more details